# Estimated total number of Higgs events

Tags: higgs, large-hadron-collider

How many Higgs events have been observed at the LHC?

I understand that this is not terribly well defined question; I'm just after an order of magnitude estimate for the excess events in, let's say, run 1 of the LHC. Are we talking 10$^1$ or 10$^5$?

Comment: Somewhere I've read that the counter is currently around 400, but it is not sure.

Comment: You are correct, there is a huge difference between "observed" and "identified". In some channels the Higgs events are copious, but the irreducible background is high, i.e. the statistics is poor. In channels with low irreducible background, OTOH the number of observed events is low. If I remember correctly, the total Higgs production at the LHC is more on the order of (several?) $10^6$, or so, but I would have to look it up.